# QGIS: Model Designer: Specify the order in which algorithms are run

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am trying to build a complicated model in the model designer. It will have, once I'm done, probablyy around 20-30 conditional branches. The branches select and extract points from a point layer with a given value and then draw lines, closed or open, depending upon the value. Unfortunately as I have it set up the model first runs the initial algorithm from each branch, meaning that when it gets to drawing onto the canvas it is only using those points that it selected most recently.

So, if you look at my model below it first select 'PX', then 'P1', then 'QX', then 'Q1' and when it moves onto drawing onto the canvas it is only using the 'Q1' selection.

My question is, does anyone know a way that I can specify "Run this brance first, then move onto the next"?

Edit: [Here is the model in question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O8neN7PrpPuNfe6G-ozBHjU1TcLz-krj/view?usp=sharing).

[image]

Comment: Try to create a reduced model that helps to understand only the actual problem, not your whole workflow. Best would be to share this dummy model for testing. Otherwise, one first has to try to recreate a model, based on many assumptions, what takes a lot of time, is cumbersome and still maybe would not reflect your very problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying, and thanks again for the help yesterday.

Comment: The project is drawing archaeological features that have been measured in with a total station. P refers to a closed line to be drawn and Q to an open line, with 1-10 showing the level being recorded and X meaning that the level is undefined.
As not every excavation has 10 levels (thank god!) I need the model to ignore a branch where there is no, for example, P2-P10.
I will try to figure out how to share the model.#

Comment: Also, 'Select 'art'' is the conditional branch using the expression 
aggregate(layer:='inlayer', aggregate:='count', expression:="art", filter:="art" IN('QX'))>0

Comment: Do not think too much in terms of your project, try to reformulate the question in a generic way to make it easier to undestand. Not sure what a "total station" is, probably irrelevant here. Also "archeological features" are not crucial to reproduce the problem, try saying like "I have a point layer and want to draw lines from it, based on condition XY. I have to re-run the whole procedure for a number of times, depending on...", so whatever "points" and "lines" represent for your project.

Comment: I have put the model into my Google Drive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O8neN7PrpPuNfe6G-ozBHjU1TcLz-krj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't share the input data publically as it is archaeologically sensetive and both my boss and the local heritage authorities would be extremely miffed at me. As in, I would get fired.
I am trying to reformulate my question a bit more clearly at the moment.

Comment: I mean: just create a dummy data layer with fantasy points somewhere in another part of the world or in the middle of the ocean, but in a realistic manner and with the kind of data structure you have. For testing the model, I anyhow need such an input layer and if I start creating one, I will either have first to start studying your whole model or otherwise create one based on my own assumptions that, however, will not satisfy your use case.

Comment: I've made very quick csv in EPSG: 25832
Thanks

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YQwJ9nTcenBaz234zObFMwZMCD6vTMktObazYoKC2WQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: When I run the model with your layer, I have 3 sets of point, but just one set is connected with a line, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zsDL.png Is your question: how to create a model that connects all 3 sets of points with a line?

Comment: That's the problem.
The model runs through the first stage of each branch and then runs the second stage. This means that it only runs the later stages of the branches on the last points selected.

The model *should* output two circles and a line. 

But as the points in the line were the last ones selected it only draws the line.

I need to find a way that it runs "branch PX" from beginning to end, then runs "branch QX" from beginning to end, and so on until all branches have been run, or skipped due to not meeting the conditions.

Comment: Instead of blowing up the comments here, it would probably be good to edit your initial question and add the necessary info there, then delete the comments. Like this, other users find the relevant information faster.

Comment: Simply use dependencies? No? Just start branch 2 when the product of branch 1 is finished!

Answer (score 0):

I created a simplified model: [download here](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/DuegMI08Xfkmxsb). It connects points with attribute value `PX` in field `art` by a closed line, those with value `QX` by an open line.

Instead of conditional branch and then somehow try to run one of the branches before the other one, you can simply duplicate your input and than run both processes in parallel. To duplicate, run the `Rename` algorithm twice to create two layers with different names. Then use these as input for each part.

If you need to re-run the same procedure over and over again for different levels, I would advice not to include that in the model (as it would get rather complex), but rather run the model in [Batch Mode](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html) - or create another model which calls the first model. This would keep things simpler.

[image]

*This is the output I get using your layer with my model. Be aware: closing paths can lead to invalid geometries (self crossing lines) as is the case with the line in the bottom center:*
[image]